# Data structure that is partially filesystem-backed?

Tags: python, data-structures, persistence

Is there an existing (Python) implementation of a hash-like data structure that exists partially on disk?  Or, can persist specific keys to some secondary storage, based on some criteria (like last-accessed-time)?

ex: "data at key K has not been accessed in M milliseconds; serialize it to persistent storage (disk?), and delete it".

I was referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512677/memory-mapped-partially-disk-based-algorithms/1512742#1512742), but I'm not sure I can digest it.

EDIT:

I've recd two excellent answers (sqlite; gdb)m; in order to determine a winner, I'll have to wait until I've tested both.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for SQLITE. A big problem that you will face down the road is concurrency/file corruption, etc and SQLite makes these very easy to avoid as it provides transactional integrity. Just define a single table with schema (primary key string key, string value). SQLite is insanely fast, especially if you wrap bunches of writes into a transaction.

GDBM IMHO also has licence problems depending on what you want to do, whereas SQLite is public domain.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for [gdbm](http://docs.python.org/library/gdbm.html):

> The gdbm module provides an interface to the GNU DBM library. gdbm objects behave like mappings (dictionaries), except that keys and values are always strings.

That's basically a dictionary on disk. You might have to do a bit of serialization depending on your use.